# Cannot access label through segment registers, error in assembly

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine16

```
INCLUDE Irvine16.inc

.data
    byteArray   BYTE 6 DUP(?)
    listSize = ($ - byteArray)
    aSum        WORD 0
    soffset = 0
.code
main PROC
    mov     ax, @data
    mov     ds, ax
    mov     cx, listSize
Loop1:
    mov     ax, 0
    movzx   ax, [byteArray + soffset]
    add     aSum, ax
    soffset = soffset + 1
    loop Loop1
    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

The error I'm getting is error "A2074:cannot access label through segment registers"

I'm trying to use the soffset to loop through the byteArray.

Comment: It might help if you included the error you received and a description of what you were trying to do.

Comment: is `soffset = soffset + 1` an assembler statement? If so, what does it do?

Comment: Yes, it's an assembler statement, although in this program it doesn't do anything, as it is never used.

Assemblers deal with symbols at very basic levels, and I presume that masm can define them, do arithmentic, test conditional assembly with symbols, the usual stuff..

Comment: It does look like it was added with the expectation that it be some sort of runtime operation, tho, I agree...

Comment: I am having this error too and the answer didn't help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's in Irvine16.inc, but I bet it is saying `.model small,...` at some point.

If you add

```
ASSUME DS:_DATA
```

then your error messages will go away, although I doubt if that's enough to make the program run.

---

Ok, I've got an idea. I think you should switch to the 32-bit examples. That's a flat model where the segment registers are set up by the OS and not used by programs. I just downloaded the irvine examples and the sample project, which happens to be 32-bits did assemble and run.

In the wierd and twisted world that is x86 machine code, the 16-bit model is quite a bit more complex than the 32-bit model, at least from the point of view of a user program.

Comment: I have to agree with Crashworks and JS, regarding soffset. As it happens, that is a valid statement in most assemblers, but it will not do what I think you think it will do.

Comment: This is homework for an assembly class that specifically requires that I use the 16-bit examples.

Comment: Ahh, OK. Well, step 1 has gotta be: get an unmodified example working.

Answer (score 3):

This error is caused by trying to assemble a DOS program (`.model` != flat) to a `COFF` .obj file. Additionally ML.EXE throws `error A2006:undefined symbol : DGROUP`. The source should be assembled to an old fashion `OMF` file. Build the file with following command lines:

```
ml.exe /omf hello.asm
link16.exe hello.obj, hello.exe;
```

`ml.exe` is part of the Visual Studio installation. `link16.exe` is part of [Irvine's library suite](http://www.kipirvine.com/asm/examples/index.htm) ("  Example programs and link library source code...").