# How to build a MS-DOS program with MASM32 in XP SP3

Tags: assembly, windows-xp, masm, masm32

I'm new to assembly.
I'm using MASM32 on WIN XP SP3.
Whenever I try to assemble the code I get a warning.

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.code
main proc
mov ah,1
int 21h
mov bl,al
mov ah,2
mov dl,bl
int 21h
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
main endp
end main
```

After assembling ASM file

> C:\masm32\coa.asm(14) : warning A4023: with /coff switch, leading underscore required for start address : main
>    Volume in drive C has no label.
>    Volume Serial Number is A868-C4EC
>    ...

please tell what to do :( 
thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you're writing real mode DOS code, rather than e.g. Win32 code? Especially since you're using MASM32.

Comment: Is there a 16 bit version of MASM you can find? For Microsoft tool sets, look for MASM 6.1x (actually ML.EXE) or older, or Visual C/C++ 2.2 or older. Visual C / C++ 4.0 and 4.1 also included Visual C/C++ 1.52 16 bit tool sets on the install cd-rom.

Comment: Read my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126364/masm32-error-a2006-error-a2074-and-warning-a4023

Answer (score 3):

You want to build a 16-bit MS-DOS program (`.model small`, `int 21h`) as a 32-bit Windows program. MASM is capable to produce MS-DOS object files but the default linker won't link that. The "warning" (in fact an error) comes from MASM since you clicked on "Assemble ASM file" in Quick Editor (qedit.exe).

The [`MASM32 SDK`](http://www.masm32.com/) comes with a 16-bit linker (link16.exe). Tell `ml.exe` to use that linker:

```
ml /Bl link16.exe; coa.asm
```

Eventually you have to write the full path e.g. `C:\masm32\bin\link16.exe`

You can add new menu points to the MASM32 Quick Editor to build a MS-DOS program. Open `menus.ini` in a text editor  (you can use the MASM32 Quick Editor `qeditor.exe`).

Scroll down to

```
&Run Program,"{b}.exe"

[&Tools]
```

Insert four lines:

```
&Run Program,"{b}.exe"
-
Assemble 16-bit .asm to .obj,cmd /C\masm32\bin\ml.exe /c "{a}" & pause
Link 16-bit .obj to .exe,cmd /C\masm32\bin\link16.exe "{b}" ,,,,, & pause
Build 16-bit .asm to .exe,cmd /C\masm32\bin\ml.exe /Bl"C:\masm32\bin\link16.exe" "{a}" & pause

[&Tools]
```

Save the file and restart the MASM32 Quick Editor.

Now you have under "Project" three new items at the end.